# HTML 5 audio with src to virtual directory with credentials

Tags: asp.net, html5-audio, iis-8, virtual-directory

I have an asp.net application which does the following: loads data about audio files (file name, path and so on) from DB and shows them in table on the page. Application uses windows authentication (this cannot be changed).

I've added html 5 audio controls to my table cells so that users could play audio files without downloading them - actually, I don't want them to be able to download files at all.

Audio files come from two network-shared directories - one is accessible by all domain users, the second one is accessible only to specific user. Audio control requires the src to be a relative url - ok, fine, so I went to IIS manager and created two virtual directories under my application. For the second, highly protected directory, I'd set credentials which should have helped my application to access files.

Result seems quite strange to me: users see audio files from the first (accessible) directory preloaded and can play them; users cannot preload and cannot play files from the second directory with preset credentials.

Problem is definitely not in the audio src itself - it is well-formed. Seems like IIS is trying to access data in the second virtual directory under credentials of current domain user and not the one, whose login and password were set on folder setup.

Is there any way to overcome this problem? Unfortunately, granting access to this directory to all users is not a chance. Changing app pool identity to that same specific user also gave no results. App users and user account for the second folder are all in the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS access file via application pool identity not login user. So when you are running an application with network share directory, please change the app pool identity to a domain user that have permission to access both. Then you can restrict login user permission via authorization rule.

Comment: Thank you, it helped - at least inspector shows me that files are accessible, so quest with IIS is passed :) Seems like the real problem is in audio codec needed to play theese wav.